# How to write a better switch-case statement?

Tags: android, android-intent, switch-statement

I am an Android newbie. I am trying to get listView value from another activity and show the specific location according to that value. In this situation with only for first switch-case it works perfect, but when I add the second switch-case It is showing me the result of first and second. How can I improve this code to show only one result for each switch statement.

```
value1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("value1", 0);
value2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("value2", 0);
value3 = getIntent().getIntExtra("value3", 0);



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  mLastLocation = location;
  if (mMarker != null)

   mMarker.remove();

  latitude = location.getLatitude();
  longitude = location.getLongitude();

  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
   .position(latLng)
   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
  mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);



  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
  mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13));


  switch (value1) {

   case 0:
    mBaniaLuca = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(BaniaLuca)
     .title("BaniaLuca"));
    mBaniaLuca.setTag(0);
    break;

   case 1:
    mBiedronka = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(Biedronka)
     .title("Biedronka"));
    mBiedronka.setTag(0);
    break;

  }
  switch (value2) {
   case 0:
    mTARITA = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(TARITA)
     .title("Tarita"));
    mTARITA.setTag(0);
    break;
  }
  switch (value3) {
   case 0:
    mCocon = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(Cocon)
     .title("Cocon"));
    mCocon.setTag(0);
    break;
  }
```

Comment: You have 3 switch statements not 2. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Every time when I add another statement , they are stacking together. Like when there is only switch(value1) for case 0 is showing me the location I wanted. But when I add the switch(value2) for case 0 it is showing me the result of both of them , same goes for the switch(value3) for case 0 it is showing me the result of switch(value1)-case0 ,switch(value2)-case0 ,switch(value3)-case0. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: You can use `mMap.clear()` to clear all markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like each time you are going through the switch case, you are 'adding' a marker.
Note the word 'adding'.

Prior to the switch case, statement, add code to remove all existing markers.  If I understand your question right, this is the behavior you want.

Comment: It was pretty simple. Thank you so much for that :)